# Notation Clarification of $G_{\uparrow\uparrow}$

Tags: quantum-spin, hamiltonian, notation, greens-functions

I am a bit confused as to what the notation
$$G_{\uparrow\uparrow}$$
on the Green fucntions means, on a paper I have come across.  Here $\hat{G}(k) = (i \omega_{l} - H_{I} - H_{P})^{-1}$.
The Hamiltonians $H_I$ and $H_P$ are both 2x2 matrices so G is 2x2 as well. $\omega_{l}$ is the Matsubara frequency. Does $G_{\uparrow\uparrow}$ mean $G_{11}$ and so on? The superconducting susceptibility is given by:

$\chi = \sum_{\omega_{l}}\sum_{k}G_{\uparrow\uparrow}(k,i \omega_{l})G_{\downarrow\downarrow}(-k,-i\omega_{l}) - G_{\downarrow\uparrow}(k,i\omega_{l})G_{\downarrow\uparrow}(-k,-i\omega_{l})$

https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3580 (supplementary section V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, in case of spin one often uses notation $G_{\sigma\sigma'}$, where $\sigma,\sigma'$ may take values $\uparrow,\downarrow$ or equivalently $1,2$ (or $0,1$). It is hard to say with certainty whether $\uparrow$ corresponds to $1$ or $2$, unless it is explicitly specified. However, in many contexts it may be of little importance, if there is no preferred direction (e.g., magnetic field.)